# How can the batch file use the username?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to make my batch file to make this:

```
set /p USERNAME=Username:
echo %USERNAME% > c:/users/%USERNAME%/Desktop/ExtraMitico/ud1.txt
```

and it says:

> The system can not find the path specified

WHY??
Please help!

Comment: `%USERNAME%` is a standard environment variable, set by the Operating System, so did you try with an alternate variable name? Also, it would be invalid for there to be more than one colon in the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much depends on exactly what you input, and as already mentioned, `username` is a variable established by the system and hence is a poor, if logical, choice.

Let's presume you use

```
set /p NAME=Username:
echo %NAME% > c:/users/%NAME%/Desktop/ExtraMitico/ud1.txt
```

You will get that message if the string input for `name` contains illegal characters like `*` or `:`.

You will also get that message if the directory `c:/users\%NAME%\Desktop\ExtraMitico\` does not exist - and note the directory-separator is `\`, not `/` - `/` is used for switches.

And you will also likely get that message if the name input contains spaces or commas and some other characters.

So - try

```
set /p NAME=Username:
MD "c:\users\%NAME%\Desktop\ExtraMitico" 2>nul
echo %NAME% > "c:\users\%NAME%\Desktop\ExtraMitico\ud1.txt"
```

where `"quoting a string"` gets over spaces etc. in the input (but not illegal characters). The `2>nul` suppresses any 'directory already exists`message from`md`.

And maybe you could forget the `set /p` statement, and use the system-set variable `username`. Depends on quite what you want to do.